# tikz: plot stepped gauss

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, plot

I need to plot a stepped gauss curve as shown below. Yet I want to do this dynamically (in text) so I can alter it later.

[image: http://media.texample.net/tikz/examples/PDF/gnuplot-tikz-terminal.pdf]

I know how to plot a smooth gauss but I really need the stepped one. Also a bar (option `ybar`) won't do because I only need the contour of the bar plot (no bars, just one curve).

I've tried:

```
\draw[black,thick] plot[id=gg,raw gnuplot] function{
    set xrange [0:7.5];
    set samples 30;
    normal(x,mu,sigma)=sigma<=0?1/0:invsqrt2pi/sigma*exp(-0.5*((x-mu)/sigma)**2);
    invsqrt2pi = 0.398942280401433;
    plot 3.5*normal(x,1.5,0.5) with histeps;
};
```

yet the `histeps` option from gnu plot doesn't kick in... (this script does work when in gnuplot).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use gnuplot in TikZ, all that happens is that you get gnuplot to generate a series of points in a table that is read and rendered using TikZ. The `histeps` option doesn't change the data, but only the rendering (in gnuplot), so it doesn't influence what you see in TikZ. Instead, you can use the TikZ option `const plot`:

```
\draw[black,thick] plot[id=gg,raw gnuplot, const plot] function{
    set xrange [0:7.5];
    set samples 30;
    normal(x,mu,sigma)=sigma<=0?1/0:invsqrt2pi/sigma*exp(-0.5*((x-mu)/sigma)**2);
    invsqrt2pi = 0.398942280401433;
    plot 3.5*normal(x,1.5,0.5);
};
```